# Addresses in USA

Tags: writing

I have a problem with street part of an address.
Can you give me some examples?
How do you write this address on an envelope? Consider a tall building. I want to send my letter to 9th floor and 4th unit, for example.

What is 799 in "799 E DRAGRAM". Is it street number or house number. How do you say?

Comment: You may find this answer useful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103454/how-to-refer-to-an-apartment-on-a-specific-floor. In many buildings, the floor number is concatenated with the apartment number, for example the apartment you refer to might be 9+04 = 904. But that is a feature of the particular building, not a general requirement of the postal service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 Yeah, It is about learning Japanese. Close it.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, an apartment in a high-rise is almost always addressed by a simple number (e.g. 1204) or a number  with an alpha suffix (e.g. 12C):

```
{addressee}
{building number on the street} {street name}
Apt {apartment number}
{City} {State abbreviation} {zipcode}

Mr Tom Jones
123 Main Street
Apt 1204
Philadelphia PA 19104
```

The apartment chunk can be positioned after the street address, and the abbreviation for "Apartment", "Apt", can appear as a #-sign:

```
Mr Tom Jones
123 Main St #1204
Philadelphia PA 19104
```

The alpha suffix on the apartment number usually indicates which unit on the floor the apartment is, but you cannot assume that every building would use this convention; some do, some don't:

```
Mr Tom Jones
123 Main St #12D
Philadelphia PA 19104
```

On some occasions a floor number is given, but that is not typical with residences but businesses:

```
Acme Widgets Inc
500 Wilson Boulevard
2nd Floor
Baltimore MD 21222
```